# Loadrunner file upload & import error

Tags: loadrunner

Here is file attachment and than import script I am getting the following error

Action.c(128): Error -26488: Could not obtain information about submitted file "C:\Users\domix\Documents\VuGen\Scripts\Credit_Report\Aaron IMPORTER.htm": _stat32 rc=-1, errno=2 [No such file or directory]. Using an empty file [MsgId: MERR-26488]

```
web_submit_data("Upload", 
"Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CustomerReports/Upload?ConsumerID=40", 
"Method=POST", 
"EncType=multipart/form-data", 
"RecContentType=application/json", 
"Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CustomerReports/Details/40", 
"Snapshot=t10.inf", 
"Mode=HTML", 
ITEMDATA, 
"Name=name", "Value=Aaron IMPORTER.htm", ENDITEM, 
"Name=chunk", "Value=0", ENDITEM, 
"Name=chunks", "Value=1", ENDITEM, 
"Name=file", "Value=Aaron IMPORTER.htm", "File=Yes", ENDITEM, 
LAST);
```

Please explain how to correct this error (This is where I am upload the file and importing it into system)

Comment: Did you look to see if the file in question was in the location specified?  Default context unless a path is provided is the directory of execution of the Virtual User

Comment: Yes I've placed the file in the Script directory where the Action.c is placed my script is passed now but I am facing another problem while running the scenario in controller this is the error I got when I execute the controller scenario


Action.c(135): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CustomerReports/DoImport?ConsumerID=36&FileName=Aaron%20IMPORTER.htm&CustomerReportID=0&_=1450704656112"

Answer (score 0):

500=you are not checking for positive expected results and branching your code when you do not receive your expected result on the page.  The originating error is likely one to two pages previous to your 500 where your business process came off the tracks and because you were not checking and branching for unexpected (just blindly accepting an HTTP 200) then you wound up in error.